# Looping through a CUSIPs and pulling data from Bloomberg using pdblp

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg, pdblp

I have a list of CUSIPs that I would like gather data for using pdblp (https://matthewgilbert.github.io/pdblp/tutorial.html).

For example:

List of CUSIPs (around 5,000 in total):

/cusip/xxxxxxxxx,
/cusip/yyyyyyyyy
...

```
con = pdblp.BCon(debug=False, port=8194, timeout=5000)
con.start()

con.ref(['/cusip/xxxxxxxxx', '/cusip/yyyyyyyyy'], ['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3',...])
```

this gives me a dataframe:

[image: Original DataFrame]

However, I would like to create a data frame which has the features as columns with the CUSIPs as either another column or an index:

[image: Wanted DataFrame]

I wasn't sure if the bdh function would get me what I was looking for either given that it is for historical data (I am looking for most recent). I guess I could also just create a long DataFrame and just melt or pivot it?

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pivot table:

```
df = con.ref(['/cusip/xxxxxxxxx', '/cusip/yyyyyyyyy'], ['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3',...])
df.pivot(index='ticker', columns='field', values='value')
```

Result:

| ticker | Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /cusip/xxxxxxxxx | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| /cusip/yyyyyyyyy | value1 | value2 | value3 |